# Decoding an image from a folder : android

Tags: android

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
            String Name = PatientInfo.getText().toString();
            String Age =  PatientAge.getText().toString();
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             Date d = new Date();
             CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
             name = s.toString() + ".jpg";
             name1 = s.toString();
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),Name + Age + gender + name1);
            File Rfolder= new File(imagesFolder , "Raw Image");
            Rfolder.mkdirs();
            File output = new File(Rfolder, name);
            callname ="/sdcard/"+Name + Age + gender+"/Raw Image/" + name;

            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {

                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                        "Image saved: ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");

           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callname);
```

i have been trying to decode the photo from a folder "Raw Image" which is inside another folder. The folder's name is give by a name, age ,gender,date and time. How can i call such a folder. Any suggestions will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not quite clear in your code.
But I think this piece of code will help you.

File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Name + Age + gender + name1);

Comment: Thanks. i want to decode a an image which is inside a folder "RawImage". The folde RawImage is inside another folder. That folder name is a person's name, age, gender, date and time. Now i have written the path of the file in a string "callname". but when i call this string its not working. I hope its clear

Comment: Have you tried the line of code I have mentioned? Have you put some value in Gender String?

Comment: yes i tried that...its not working...and yes there are values for gender string

Comment: what if there is no raw image folder How will be the path..callname ="/sdcard/"+Name + Age + gender + name;Is it a correct way

Comment: If that's the case then it will be like this callname ="/sdcard/"+Name + Age + gender +"/"+ name; But you should really use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of "/sdcard/".

Comment: thanks it worked... but why you recommend Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of "/sdcard/" anyhow both will work na?

Comment: If it worked on your device then its fine, but sometimes certain devices use a different path for the external storage while some devices might not have external storage at all(like Nexus devices). So developers usually avoid using "/sdcard/".

On the other hand, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is a system API and will always be supported by all device manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

don't leave space in the folder name `"Raw image"`.
if you dont care about how file name looks outside your app then instead of creating such deep structure( `/sdcard/Name + Age + gender+"/Raw Image/" + name;`), create `/sdcard/YOUR_APP_NAME/images/{HASH_OF_KEY_VALUES}.jpg`. here KEY_VALUES is name,age,gender, and some id.

Comment: thanks... but its important of how the file name looks. the folder name consist of age gender name...so there is a bit confusion for giving the path